# My admin panel and upload

Tags: php, tinymce

I have written an admin panel for my site (im beginner in php).
In content.php I have insert tinyMCE editor. I want to upload images from editor.
What is the best way to do this. (not very familiar with javascript)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [TinyBrowser](http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php) for a very long time without any problems whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is the absolute best image upload manager for TinyMCE but it seems to work well. However, it comes with a pricetag.

From the guys who maintain TinyMCE:
[MCImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php)

Comment: MCImageManager is commercial :(
It can be any other editor to uploading file to any folder I want.
Thank you Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I use TinyUpload - http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=12624

Free and works great.